# macOS - view and read the Purpose and Description for macOS each process

Tags: macos, command-line

Many times I am able to read the Purpose and Description for each macOS process by simply execute the `man` command.  Example `man rapportd` or `man WiFiAgent` etc. etc.

But other times, the `man` command does not have any entry for other macOS processes.  Example `man loginwind` or `man PowerChime` or etc. etc.

Does Apple has an official website with a simple search query criteria where I can find the Purpose and Description for each macOS processes?

I am just interesting in the Purpose and Description of what a specific macOS process does.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, there is less documentation online than ships with the OS.

Many but not all parts of the software is open sourced:

- https://opensource.apple.com/

More of the manual pages used to be published, but Apple’s efforts seemed geared to focus on developer documentation and user guides over manual pages and process lists.

There are excellent books however to fill the first party gap:

- http://newosxbook.com/index.php?page=book
- https://www.peachpit.com/store/macos-support-essentials-11-apple-pro-training-series-9780137345953

First party training is also available:

- https://training.apple.com/us/en/recognition

Comment: *bmike* is correct. However, a web search for `MacOS loginwind` might give you a lot of information.